# Vertical aligning content of PathListBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, vertical-alignment, blend

I have a control containing a PathListBox from Blend SDK (see XAML below). The items inside are of identical width and various height. Currently, the midpoint of the items follow the arc's path (see the picture) i.e. **they are clearly vertically arranged 'center'.  However, I would like the items 'top' vertically aligned**, so their top follows the arc's path. How can I do that?

[image]

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ec:PathListBox Margin="160,290,-30,-250">
        <ec:PathListBox.LayoutPaths>
            <ec:LayoutPath SourceElement="{Binding ElementName=arc}" 
                Padding="-25"  FillBehavior="NoOverlap" 
                Distribution="Even"  Span="0.5"/>
        </ec:PathListBox.LayoutPaths>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="103" Width="100"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="120" Width="100"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="140" Width="100"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="265" Width="100"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Width="100"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="265" Width="100"/>
    </ec:PathListBox>
    <ed:Arc x:Name="arc" 
        ArcThickness="10"  ArcThicknessUnit="Pixel"  Margin="160,290,-30,-250" 
        Stretch="None"  Stroke="Transparent"  StartAngle="-7" 
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"  StrokeThickness="3" 
        Opacity="0.155" Fill="LightGray">
        <ed:Arc.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" ScaleX="-1"/>
                <SkewTransform AngleY="-17" AngleX="-16"/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </ed:Arc.RenderTransform>
    </ed:Arc>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please update yr question to include that the control is part of Blend SDK (as per http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/tutorials/pathlistbox/) also an extra tag will increase the chances to be answerer for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change margins of your rects:

```
...
<Rectangle Fill="Green" Height="103" Width="100" Margin="0,130,0,0"/>
<Rectangle Fill="Green" Height="120" Width="100" Margin="0,120,0,0"/>
<Rectangle Fill="Green" Height="140" Width="100" Margin="0,140,0,0"/>
<Rectangle Fill="Green" Height="265" Width="100" Margin="0,265,0,0"/>
<Rectangle Fill="Green" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="0,100,0,0"/>
<Rectangle Fill="Green" Height="265" Width="100" Margin="0,265,0,0"/>
...
```

I'm after trying it myself on Blend4 and it works.

Comment: what version of Blend are you using?

Comment: That is a nice trick, I will take a look. In reality, the items are complex UI elements dynamically generated and their height is content dependent. I just simplified the question with rectangles. But if works I coud databind the margin to the Height.

Comment: Should make no difference, you could use a converter as Thickness is immutable.